# How to allow only english characters in yii model rule for textfield

Tags: php, yii

Yii allow English characters in textfield through model rules
how is it possible

only characters allow English language not Hindi, Marathi or other languages.
my model rule is:

```
array('description', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/[^0-9a-zA-Z_-]/'),
```

when i submit this text

Lorem Ipsum फक्त मुद्रण आणि typesetting उद्योगाच्या बनावट मजकूर आहे. Lorem Ipsum अज्ञात प्रिंटर प्रकार एक ठेंगणे सपाट घेतला आणि एक प्रकार नमुना पुस्तक करण्यास Scrambled तेव्हा इ.स.चे 1500 चे दशक, पासून कधीही उद्योग च्या मानक बनावट मजकूर केले आहे. हे मूलत: जसाच्या तसा उर्वरित, शतके, परंतु देखील इलेक्ट्रॉनिक typesetting मध्ये उडी नाही फक्त पाच गेलो आहे. हे Lorem Ipsum परिच्छेद असलेले Letraset पत्रके च्या प्रकाशात 1960 मध्ये लोकप्रिय, आणि अधिक अलीकडे Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum आवृत्त्या समावेश Aldus PageMaker जसे डेस्कटॉप प्रकाशन सॉफ्टवेअरसह फक्त मुद्रण आणि typesetting उद्योगाच्या बनावट मजकूर आहे. Lorem Ipsum अज्ञात प्रिंटर प्रकार

gives a exception like this.

```
CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA4\xAB\xE0\xA4\x95...' for column 'description' at row 1. The SQL statement executed was: UPDATE `mmm_specialoffer` SET `id`=:yp0, `shop_id`=:yp1, `category`=:yp2, `service_id`=:yp3, `title`=:yp4, `description`=:yp5, `offer_from_date`=:yp6, `offer_to_date`=:yp7, `added_date`=:yp8 WHERE `mmm_specialoffer`.`id`=8

 throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: {error}',
```

thanks.

Comment: please paste here the model rules you have currently, or any research you've done in the subject

Comment: where do you mean to use this? in a form? just as a simple text string...? details, please!... ah, and some code you tried would be nice too

Comment: i use this in form and i have posted my code in my question please see that.

Comment: I'm not expert in regex, but everywhere i looked just now, i saw a `u` at the end after the last slash, like this: `'pattern'=>'/[^0-9a-zA-Z_-]/u'`... give it a try...

Comment: @webeno i try your code but it gives same exception .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it -

`/^[0-9a-zA-Z_-\s]*$/i` - allows only numbers, alphabets, underscore, hyphen and space.

`/^['0-9a-zA-Z_-\s]*$/i` - allows apostrophe too.